# How can I exclude certain routes from maintenance mode?

Tags: routes, maintenance-mode

I am trying to make certain routes exempt from maintenance mode by adding the option _maintenance_access to the route and setting it to TRUE.

I think (although I'm not 100%) that this works because in [Drupal\Core\Site\MaintenanceMode](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Site%21MaintenanceMode.php/class/MaintenanceMode/8.2.x) there is the following method which checks for the _maintenance_access option and returns false if it is present -

```
public function applies(RouteMatchInterface $route_match) {
  if (!$this->state->get('system.maintenance_mode')) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  if ($route = $route_match->getRouteObject()) {
    if ($route->getOption('_maintenance_access')) {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }

  return TRUE;
}
```

I have followed [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones) guide on drupal.org on how to alter existing routes

Here is my mymodule.services.yml file

```
services:
  mymodule.route_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\Routing\MaintenanceModeRouteSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Here is my MaintenanceModeRouteSubscriber class

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

class MaintenanceModeRouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($route = $collection->get('entity.node.canonical')) {
      $route->addOptions(['_maintenance_access' => TRUE]);
    }
  }
}
```

But this is not working as when viewing this route (any node) it is still in maintenance mode.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Do you see any errors when clearing the cache with `drush cr`? Try to print debug messages which you then see from the command line like `var_dump($route);`.

Comment: I'm not sure what is going on (no errors), what happens when you try to view a node when not logged in and when maintenance mode is on? Does it allow you to view it?

Comment: Yes, I can view nodes, other pages return the maintenance message. Did you try to print a debug message from alterRoutes() to see if it is working when clearing the cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override the service directly.

**mymodule.services.yml**

```
services:
  maintenance_mode: # same ID as declared in core.services.yml
    class: Drupal\mymodule\Services\CustomMaintenanceMode # point to your class
    arguments: ['@state']
```

**mymodule/src/Services/CustomMaintenaceMode.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Services;

use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Site\MaintenanceMode;

class CustomMaintenanceMode extends MaintenanceMode {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function exempt(AccountInterface $account) {
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface && $node->getType() == 'article') {
      return TRUE;
    }
    else {
      return $account->hasPermission('access site in maintenance mode');
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, would overiding the service directly allow me to, say for instance, allow one node type and disallow another from the maintenance mode access?

Comment: Yes, but I'm babysitting right now, I'll show ya later.

Comment: @hck12685 after testing this out, turns out you need to override the `exempt()` method as overriding the `applies()` method to TRUE didn't do it.

Comment: Yes I figured that out, thanks. It does seem to be working now as the maintenance mode is gone, but now I am left with a "The requested page could not be found. " message. So some more debugging required. If it is anything related to this question I will post the solution back here.

Comment: Probably due to some contrib/custom module introducing that, because I'm not getting that on a fresh D8 install.

Comment: I assume you don't have that problem when logged in as admin and maintenance is on.

Comment: Yes that is correct, no problem when logged in as admin. I will try test on a new install. Thanks

Comment: Needing to use the "same ID as declared in core.services.yml" is in direct contradiction with the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones#s-altering-existing-routes) which claims it works the way the question's code is written.  Any insights?  Is the documentation incorrect?

Comment: @phils the documentation is correct. This just an alternate way of overriding a service which by some may not be considered best practice.